# Can these routes co-exist?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-3

Can anyone tell me how (and what would be the best way) routes can be configured to allow the following URL's to co-exist in ASP.Net MVC 3?

```
/Product/a38e8843-195f-4ee8-b89a-2549b753a307
```

maps to Index action on ProductController width **id = a38e8843-195f-4ee8-b89a-2549b753a307**

```
/MemberShip/LogOn
```

maps to LogOn action on MemberShip controller

I figure I'll have to somehow have to do some configuration based on the specific controller - I just don't know how! :)

Comment: Only if they are respectful to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the following routes before the default routes:

```
"Products/{productId}" and "MemeberShip/{action}"
```

Each one pointing to its specific controller and action.

Create your actions normally:

public class Products : Controller
{
public Action ViewProduct(string productId)
{
...

public class Membership : Controller
{
public Action Logon()
{
...

And when mapping your routes, add two specific routes:
routes.MapRoute(
    "ViewProduct",
    "Products/{productId}",
    new { controller = "Products", action = "ViewProduct"}
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "Logon",
    "Membership/{action}",
    new { controller = "Membership"}
);

If you are using the default routes, this last one isn't necessary, because it is on the pattern "controller/action".

Here you can find a lot of tutorials on MVC, and surely, routing:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-overview-cs

Comment: Actually the second one should be fine with the default route

Comment: Yep, you don't need the second route

Comment: I'd also recommend putting a regex constraint on productID (I'm assuming that your productIds are standardised) so other actions on the products controller can fall through.